# Infimum of a set of a sequence of numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the sequence $\{ y_{n} \}$ of real numbers such that $\sup\{\left | y_{n} \right |:n\in \mathbb{N}\}=4$. Find $\inf \left\{\frac{\left | y_{n} \right |}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

Since $4=\sup\{\left | y_{n} \right |:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, then it follows that $0\leq \frac{\left | y_{n} \right |}{n}\leq \frac{4}{n}$, and hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\ \frac{\left | y_{n} \right |}{n}=0.$$ I feel like the infimum of the set: $\{\frac{\left | y_{n} \right |}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ should be zero, but a rigorous proof eludes me. It's obvious that $0$ is a lower bound for the set, but I don't know how to prove that it is the greater lower bound for the set. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take $\varepsilon > 0$, and find an $n$ such that $\lvert y_n\rvert/n < \varepsilon$. That proves that the infimum is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks fr the hint! using your hint, it's clear now how to solve the problem.

Comment: More generally, if the limit of a sequence $(a_n)$ exists, then always $\inf a_n\le\liminf a_n=\lim a_n= \limsup a_n\le \sup a_n$ and if it doesn't, then still $\inf a_n\le\liminf a_n\le \limsup a_n\le \sup a_n$